# Is it possible for VBA excel to look for a repeat variable from a pool of variables (ie. 10k), group them together

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it is possible for VBA excel to group all similar variables together for example, voltage_test or current_test from a large pool of variables with different test names. Besides that, is it possible also for VBA excel to add up all the values that tagged with the same input name.

I have tried using the pivot table and it seems to work as it helps to filter those with values tagged. Unfortunately, these results happened randomly, sometimes voltage_test can be = 3, sometimes it can also not be = 3. There are also many other undetermined variables such as short_circuit_tests and so on.

Say for example, (Those variables with a 1 means i need to copy)

```
             A                      B                C                   D
  1      voltage_test               1
  2      current_test               1
  3      voltage_test               1
  4      voltage_test        
  5      current_test               
  6      short_circuit_test
  .
  .
  .
 10000   voltage_test               1
```

What i'm trying to do is to group all similar variables together and also copying the variables along with the number of times it appears onto another worksheet.

After using VBA to group the similar variables, I will have something like the following

```
          A                B
1     voltage_test         3
2     current_test         1
```

I need to copy this and paste it into another spreadsheet. short_circuit_test will not be copied as it does not repeat itself.

I have thought of using the if-else statement, but it gets a bit lengthy or rather crazy when the tests adds up to 10,000.

Do share your ideas, I will greatly appreciate your help! Thanks!!!

I'm sorry for those who have came in and post your comments, I have revised my questions, I hope this cleared up some of the doubts!

Comment: your question is rather unclear. What is this "pool of variables"? Where do the data come from?

Comment: Instead of assigning the "1", can you copy the variables to a new array? So you would have an array containing all the variables that you need to copy.

Comment: You can use ADO with Excel http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: if you need to access all the variables by name in your VBA code a scripting dictionary might be what you are looking to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, I have revised my questions! Sorry for the unnecessary inconvenience.

Comment: This is quite a significant revision that makes all previous answers irrelevant... which is a bit frustrating. I suggest you show us what you have tried. Then someone may be willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple `AutoFilter' on column B either manually or with VBA and then copy the resulting records to a second sheet

To filter "1" values in column B of the first sheet and then copy columns A&B from the filtered result to the second sheet with VBA

```
Sub QuickFilter()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
    ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[b1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp))
    rng1.AutoFilter 1, "1"
    If rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then rng1.Offset(0, -1).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, 2).Copy ws2.[a1]
    ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, i have revised my questions. I will try using your code. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear and you are making us guess what you are trying to achieve... But this is my guess:

You have data on Sheet1 that is formatted something like this:

```
row\col A                   B
1       test                1
2       test1               
3       test2               1
...
...
...
10000   test10000           1
```

You want this to be the result on Sheet 2:

```
row\col A                   
1       test                
2       test2               
...
...
n       test10000
```

where `n` represents the number of "tests" whose value is 1.

The following code will do this:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim i1 As Long

iRow = 1
i1 = 0
Do
    If Sheet1.Cells(iRow, 2) = 1 Then
        i1 = i1 + 1
        Sheet2.Cells(i1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(iRow, 1)
    End If
    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop While Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(iRow, 1))
```

Comment: Hi, I have revised my questions abit, will try and use your code. Thank you so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

User1204868,

If you are interested in a NON VBA method then you can use this Excel Formula.

```
=SUM(($B$2:$B$10)*($A$2:$A$10=E2)*($B$2:$B$10=1))
```

You have to enter this formula as an array formula (Press CTL+SHIFT+ENTER)

**Edit**: Snapshot attached.

[image]

Comment: hi thanks. I have tried using the pivot table, it did help me producing similar results. But i need VBA to help me predict what will be shown in the pivot table, because i need to use macro to shorten the time spent in looking for the values and variables.